# How can we use " share" in various sentences? (verb)

Tags: prepositions

(I mean the "share" which means **"dividing"**), I'm a bit confused about prepositions that can be used after this "share", would you explain it with examples please?

Example 1 : I shared my photos **with** my friend

Example 2 : I shared my photos **to** my friend

Now which one is correct ? Both or one of them ? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the sense of *share* in your examples is a new one coming from the use of social media.  Oxford Languages says "post or repost (something) on a social media site or application". I searched Google Ngrams and found *one* reference to 'sharing photos *to* social media apps'.

The traditional usage is "share something *between* two or more people" (divide it into equal parts) or "share something *with* someone else" (keep half for yourself and give them half).